# Replace text in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, ssh

I have a config file I want to edit through ssh and need a smart command(or commands) to replace some text in it. File is like this:

```
[vol1]
path = /folder
allowed = 10.10.10.1
public=yes
```

I need to modify the allowed part, precisely to add some IP's blank delimited, like this:

```
[vol1]
path = /folder
allowed = 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.9
public=yes
```

Tried with **sed** bash function but I can't make it work as I want to, just as I thought it's a piece of cake.
Just another info, there is lots of chunks of text like this in config file.
IP adresses are not from the sam pool, derived or smth like that(can be very different) and IP address format is already checked so no need to do that.
Information I have is that I have to append given address in chunk starting with [vol1], precisely in the allowed section of that chunk.
I hope I sound clear enough.

Any ideas?

Comment: `sed` is the right tool for this.  What did you try?

Comment: How smart does the script need to be about the IP address you're appending? If it's some transformation of the original IP address, a simple script in Perl/Python/whatever might be more appropriate  than `sed`.

Comment: If this just has to be done one time, try your text editor. If it has to be done repeatedly, it may be better to generate the file from a template than to edit in place.

Comment: @Michael Burr Doesn't need to be very smart but it has to be done only with bash commands, I cannot use some scripting language for this.

Comment: @harpo used smth like in the answer below given by linker but didn't work

Comment: @Kaz It doesn't have to be done repeatedly, only by request, everything is done through ssh so no text editor is available, and I cannot use vi function or any other with some sort of interaction

Answer (score 4):

```
ssh user@host sed -i '/allowed =/s/$/ 10.10.10.9/' /path/to/file
```

Comment: This solution works just fine for my initial question, but I wasn't clear about what I need, please review my question again, I hope you will have the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in `sed` should do the trick:

```
cat /path/to/file.txt | sed 's/10.10.10.1/& &/g'
```

To match any IP:

```
cat /path/to/file.txt | sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/& &/g'
```

If you want to change your delimiter, just edit the right operand of the `sed` command, and put whatever delimiter you want. For example to use a tab:

```
cat /path/to/file.txt | sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/&\t&/g'
```

Comment: Yeah I know you could just put the filename in the end, I just find it more intuitive to read from left to right like this.

Comment: @downvoter: would be great if you can explain, as this solves the problem as phrased in the question.

Comment: @linker: I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect that it's because the added IP address isn't going to be the same as the matched IP address.  At least that's what the example in the question implies. Unfortunately, the OP doesn't say exactly how the added IP address needs to be derived, so it's hard to say if a simple `sed` script can do what's needed easily.

Comment: @linker, well i am not the downvoter, but the reason may be what Michael says.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply but here's what I need. @linker Problem is that I don't know the address that is in the file so I cannot do appending since I don't know where to append. I know the name of the chunk where to put it (eg.[vol1]) and thats all.

Comment: @Michael Burr Also adressess are not derived in any way (they can be from a totally diferent pool). Sorry for not being precise at first, hope you understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the editor too:

```
 echo -e "/10.10.10.1\ns/\$/ 10.10.10.9\nx\n" | ex file_to_change
```